# Centralized management of fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been coding android apps for a couple of years now and when I started fragments was the way to go so I've been using them since.

From the beginning I thought the lifecycle and handling of fragments was a mess and tried a couple of different approaches with a single activity or 1 activity per groups of fragments etc.
I was more comfortable with the single activity approach but then ran into problem where to show and hide fragments etc.

I tried to have all logic for showing/hiding a fragment in its own class and then using a model-notifier pattern for pushing out a message containing information about which fragment to show and hide. The last thing I tried was to have a "FragmentService" that gets notified, using EventBus, with a message (DTO) containing information about what fragment to show/hide and a bundle to pass with it.

I'm not totally satisfied with my architecture for managing fragment yet so now I'm curious how you solve this problems? I want every fragment to be loosely coupled from each other and able to start Fragment1 from Fragment2, 3 or 4 etc.

**Can this be solved in a centralized and understandable way?**